# How to stop persistent Windows Updates download of *.etl files

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I have disabled all Winodws Updates Services but Windows 10 still downloads these `*.etl` files in the background to folders inside `%temp%`. Monitoring the directory I found out that it is `svchost.exe` that is writting those `*.etl` files.

`R:\Temp\_E1F403B2-5E24-48CC-9BC9-B1385FB69348\WindowsUpdate.20210409.213107.826.1.etl`

*In my case %temp% is R:\Temp*

There are plenty of them and it never stop downloading.

[image]

Even after stopping those services (***even deleting their entries from the registry***) they will come back magically after a couple days.

> Update Orchestrator Service
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\UsoSvc]

> [Windows Update Medic Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59077619/how-to-disable-windows-update-medic-service)
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WaaSMedicSvc]

> Windows Update
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv

So my question, is there a way to completely and effectively stop Windows 10 from persistently downloading updates in the background? Is there a way to completely prevent Windows from creating `*.etl` files?

Windows 10 LTSC Version 1809 Buid 17763.1294

Comment: Control widows updates with this tool>>>https://win10.guru/toolkit-item-windows-update-minitool-wumt/

Comment: @Moab Not a reliable tool. I'd use O&O Shutup instead.

Comment: These are *e*vent *t*racing *l*og files rather than downloaded updates. I suspect breaking these services' logging functionalities would be much more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas because not even O&O Shutup is fixing it. As i mentioned. Windows Update returns after a while.

Comment: Cool.. cool.. I will delete my comment. I was simply confused.

Comment: @Azevedo Been using it since it was coded, been reliable for me on 20 PC's. Absolutely stops Windows automatic updates and you can hide any update you don't want.